# skip database connection with mysql while doing testing in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa, build.gradle, spring-test

I am using below dependency(in gradle) in my spring boot project to get it work with mysql

```
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootCloudVersion}")
```

And have provided the Datasource setting in my application.properties file below:-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

and it is running good.

While executing Test cases in Spring Boot,
I want to skip creating database connection with mysql, as I am not getting anything from database, Instead I have mocked (using mockito) and which is the correct way.

I have searched on google and stackoverflow and I am not able to find the solution about "how can I skip creating database connection while executing test cases".

Can someone help me out about this or guide

My Test File :-

```
package com.myproject.utility.services.impl;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")    
public class UserServicesImplTest {
  private static final String MOBILE = "123456";

  @MockBean
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Test
  public void verify(){
    when(userRepository.findAll().thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    userService.verifyDetails(MOBILE);
  }
}
```

Comment: You test looks like very simple, maybe you do not need startup spring context. just create new object for testing and mock required fields. For injecting fields you can calling `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide a 'test configuration' which you can place inside your test class, then Spring will use it instead of production one:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest    
public class UserServicesImplTest {

  private static final String MOBILE = "123456";

  @MockBean private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired private UserService userService;

  @Test
  public void verify(){
    when(userRepository.findAll().thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    userService.verifyDetails(MOBILE);
  }

  @Configuration
  @Import(UserService.class)
  static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    UserRepository userRepository() {
      return mock(UserRepository.class);
    }
  }
}
```

More info is here: [Detecting Test Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)

Comment: Thanks @Cepr0 for the solution.

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't allow me to do so. May because this is my first post on stackoverflow or less reputation.

Comment: @SunilJindal just set 'check mark' to the left of the answer... )